# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'clothing_products' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

When I click on error message it takes me to the map method in my service class where I perform the GET request. clothing_products is defined in my interface, so i don't see the problem

ClothingProduct class:

```
export class ClothingProduct {
    description:string;
    category:string;
}
```

ClothingProductService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ClothingProduct } from '../common/clothing-product';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClothingProductService {
  private baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/clothing';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  // create GET request which returns of type Observable
  getClothingProductList(): Observable<ClothingProduct[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<GetResponse>(this.baseURL).pipe(
      map(response => response.embedded.clothing_products)
   );
  }

}
// map the incoming json to clothing_products
interface GetResponse
{
  embedded:
  {
    clothing_products: ClothingProduct[];
  }
}
```

ClothingListComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClothingProductService } from 'src/app/services/clothing-product.service';
import { ClothingProduct } from 'src/app/common/clothing-product';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clothing-list',
  templateUrl: './clothing-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clothing-list.component.css']
})
export class ClothingListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private clothingService: ClothingProductService) { }
  clothing_products: ClothingProduct[];
  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
     this.listClothingProducts();
   //this.reloadData();
  }
  //reloadData(){ 
   // return this.clothing_products = this.clothingService.getClothingList();
  //}

  // subscribe to GET request
  listClothingProducts()
  {
    this.clothingService.getClothingProductList().subscribe(
      data => { 
        this.clothing_products = data;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

clothinglistcomponent.html:

```
<p *ngFor="let tempClothingProducts of clothing_products">
    {{tempClothingProducts.category}} {{tempClothingProducts.description}}
</p>
```

Clothing_Article_RestController:

```
package com.example.Clothing.controller;

import com.example.Clothing.entity.Clothing_Article;
import com.example.Clothing.service.Clothing_Article_Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
@CrossOrigin( origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class Clothing_Article_RestController {
    Clothing_Article_Service clothingArticleService;
    @Autowired
    Clothing_Article_RestController(Clothing_Article_Service clothingArticleService)
    {
        this.clothingArticleService = clothingArticleService;
    }
    // get a list of clothing
    @GetMapping("/clothing")
    public List<Clothing_Article> findAll(){return clothingArticleService.findAll();}

    // GET Request by id
    @GetMapping("/clothing/{clothingId}")
    public Clothing_Article getClothingArticle(@PathVariable int clothingId)
    {
         Clothing_Article clothing_article = clothingArticleService.findById(clothingId);
         if(clothing_article == null) throw new RuntimeException("Clothing not found, ID: "+clothingId);
         return clothing_article;
    }
    @PostMapping("/clothing")
    public Clothing_Article postClothingArticle(@RequestBody Clothing_Article clothing_article)
    {
        clothing_article.setId(0);
        clothingArticleService.save(clothing_article);
        return clothing_article;
    }
    // request for put/updating existing category/description by id
    @PutMapping("/clothing")
    public Clothing_Article updateClothingArticle(@RequestBody Clothing_Article clothing_article)
    {
        clothingArticleService.save(clothing_article);
        return clothing_article;
    }
    // delete a clothing article by id
    @DeleteMapping("/clothing/{clothingId}")
    public String deleteClothing(@PathVariable int clothingId)
    {
        Clothing_Article clothing_article = clothingArticleService.findById(clothingId);
        if (clothing_article == null) throw new RuntimeException("clothing id not found "+clothingId);
        clothingArticleService.deleteById(clothingId);
        return "deleted clothing article id " + clothingId;
    }
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuxr5.jpg)

Comment: Just because you have `clothing_products` defined on your interface, doesn't mean the object will actually exist. Look at what's coming back from your GET request and see what `response.embedded` actually is. You'll see `clothing_products` will be undefined.

Comment: Adding to what @Viqas already explained, property 'clothing_products' of undefined means `response.embedded` itself will be undefined. And you are trying to access property clothing_products of an undefined item.